# Write Record in end row or update a row where multiple users using Google Sheet Live

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a scenario where a user submits a form that I preprocess via Apps Script and write/update an entry to the Google Sheet. If it's a new entry, it will be as the last row. The problem I am facing is that the sheet where I am writing data is continuously getting used by different team members as well. They were using different filters to see and filter the data whenever needed. My script fails when a filter is in an active state on the sheet or someone is working on the sheet and the script just doesn't write it at all. I have to make sure whatever the state of the sheet is, the new entry should be added as the last row and if the uniqueID(let's say email) of the user already exists in the sheet, then the other info to be updated in the relevant row.

I have used a protection approach to lock the sheet when I receive data from the form, and only the script has permission to write the data in the sheet at that time, and then the script releases the lock.

For filtering, I am trying to use an approach that when the script receives an input, I am trying to save the state of filters by saving the filter criteria and removing the filter so my sheet has no active filter (or different views) and then get the very last row and add data in the next row of it. After that, I am trying to re-assign those filters to bring the sheet in its original form.

```
  var spreadsheet_eoID = "17ZYhaYkskskskxRXVZCoZxVE6cfoSEqIDnnwePSjsj";
  var spreadsheet_eoi = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet_eoID);
  var eoi_tracker = spreadsheet_eoi.getSheetByName('Tracker_Test');
  lockRowsWhileScriptIsRunning(eoi_tracker, 2, eoi_tracker.getLastRow()); //Locking the sheet

  var headerRow = 5; // Row containing headers
  var headers = eoi_tracker.getRange(headerRow, 1, 1, eoi_tracker.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  
  var defaultFilter = eoi_tracker.getRange(5, 2, 1, eoi_tracker.getLastColumn()).getFilter(); // My headers are in Row 5 and from 2nd column onwards - 

  var filterState = [];
  for (var columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= eoi_tracker.getLastColumn(); columnIndex++) {
    var criteria = defaultFilter.getColumnFilterCriteria(columnIndex).copy().build();
    filterState.push(criteria);
  }
  defaultFilter.remove(); 

  var existing_data = eoi_tracker.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 6; i < existing_data.length; i++) { // Start from row 7 (excluding header rows)
      
      var rowData = existing_data[i];
      var crmid = rowData[headers.indexOf('CRM ID')].toString(); // Assuming password is in column D
      var delivery_code = rowData[headers.indexOf('Delivery Code')].toString();  

      if (crmid == data["CRM ID"] && delivery_code == data["Delivery Code"]) {
        console.log("Exiting, as data is already existing!! ")
        
        // unlockRowsAfterScriptIsDone(eoi_tracker,2, eoi_tracker.getLastRow()); //Unlock the sheet!
        removeExistingProtections(eoi_tracker); //Remove all protections after done

        return;
    }
    }

  var lastRow = eoi_tracker.getLastRow();
  var lastRowRange = eoi_tracker.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, eoi_tracker.getLastColumn());
  var lastRowValues = lastRowRange.getValues()[0];
  var lastEOIId = lastRowValues[headers.indexOf("EOI ID")];

  var nextEOIId = generateCRMID(lastEOIId);

  data["EOI ID"] = nextEOIId; // Using square brackets


  var nextRow = lastRow + 1;
  var nextRowRange = eoi_tracker.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, eoi_tracker.getLastColumn());

  lastRowRange.copyTo(nextRowRange);

  var lastRow = eoi_tracker.getLastRow();

  resetRow(eoi_tracker, lastRow);

  

  for (var key in data){
    var columnIndex = headers.indexOf(key);
    if (columnIndex !== -1) {
      var value = data[key];
      var org_cell = eoi_tracker.getRange(lastRow, columnIndex + 1);
      org_cell.setValue(value);
    }

}

// After making changes, restore the filter state
for (var columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= filterState.length; columnIndex++) {
  var criteria = filterState[columnIndex - 1];
  if (criteria) {
    eoi_tracker.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(columnIndex, criteria);
  }
}
```

Remove Protections on Sheet

```
function removeExistingProtections(sheet) {
  
  // Get a list of existing protections on the sheet
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

  // Iterate through the protections and remove them
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    protections[i].remove();
  }
  console.log("Final Protection Removal..")
  sheet.protect().remove();

}
```

Applying Locking/Protection on Sheet Range

```
  function lockRowsWhileScriptIsRunning(sheet, startRow, endRow){

  var numRows = endRow - startRow + 1;
  var numColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, numColumns);
  
  // Create a protection for the range
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Script Lock');
  
  // Ensure that the protection only applies when the script is running
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }

  Utilities.sleep(10000); //10 sec
}
```

Error at this line with the above approach

```
var criteria = defaultFilter.getColumnFilterCriteria(columnIndex).copy().build();
```

> Exception: Those columns are out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

### Recommendation: Adjust the `for` loop's column index

The variable `defaultFilter` captures the filters from the second column onwards. However, your `for` loop's `columnIndex` starts from the first column, which is outside of the `defaultFilter`'s range. Running your script with the `columnIndex` set to 2 produced a different error though but I was able to make it work by modifying the loop to only act on columns that have a filter.

Try changing your `for` loop to this:

```
  for (var columnIndex = 2; columnIndex <= eoi_tracker.getLastColumn(); columnIndex++) {
    if(defaultFilter.getColumnFilterCriteria(columnIndex) != null){
      var criteria = defaultFilter.getColumnFilterCriteria(columnIndex).copy().build();
      filterState.push(criteria);
    }
  }
```

Note that you would also have to adjust the index of the `for` loop that's setting the filter criteria as well.

Comment: Let me know if this works for you or if you have any questions regarding the answer I posted.

Comment: Hi @veerg404, was the answer above able to fix your issue? 

Feel free to let me know if you have any questions regarding it.

Comment: Hi @duuEyn, sorry it didn;t work as I am getting filterState as empty via this approach. My filters are in 5th row and from 2nd column to last column of the sheet. Do you think if there is any issue with the indexes given in defaultFilter?

Comment: Hi @veerg404. Thanks for letting me know. The filterState's not returning an empty value on my end. I'm not seeing anything wrong with the indexes you specified as well. Are you perhaps getting an error that the filterState is empty when running `setColumnFilterCriteria()`?